# Less first-child

Tags: css, less

Why isn't my first-child selector working in Less?

```
.leftPanel{
    margin:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    width:620px;
    margin-left:10px;
    select{
        width:300px;    
        &:first-child{
            margin-right: 30px;             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fair enough. still doesn't answer the question though.

Comment: You have received answers for 8 questions but only accepted one answer. This discourages people from answering your questions.

Comment: thanks didn't know about that. will do from now on. What if there's no suitable answer?

Comment: That question is answered in the very same link, under "What should I do if none of the answers is suitable?"

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if no answers are suitable, *simply don't accept one*. You don't have to accept an answer on every question.

Comment: Thanks have updated past questions now

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are specifying that if the first child element inside a `.leftPanel` is a `<select>`, it should have `margin-right: 30px;`. If you are trying to apply this rule to the first child element **inside** the `<select>` (which should always be an `<option>`), try replacing `&:first-child` with `option:first-child`.

Comment: I see your point. I am trying to target the first select box inside the left panel

Comment: Is the *first element* inside `.leftPanel` a `select`? If not, that's your problem.